# jQuery plugin for making small animated popups?

Tags: jquery

I would like to know if there is any jQuery plugin like the one in this site:

http://www.theverge.com/2013/8/22/4645454/back-to-school-2013-the-verge-guide#intro

If you click the faces on the bottom right corner you reach a session with small circles. A small popup comes up if you hover on the small circles.

Any suggestion for a plugin taht does this?

Comment: I believe what you really want is the CSS3 animation, as that is what being used in that website. And you don't really need a plugin, just the right CSS3 and thus depends on how you want to present your popup.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is quickly done using [animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/). In this case a bit of jQuery is involved. My point is you don't really need a plugin when it really is just one `.hover` (or not even jQuery if you use your CSS `:hover`).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vLSWH/3/

EDIT: Updated fiddle, wrong link before.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.they created a very long page..
>   2.those three faces are similar to three buttons.
>   3.then on click of those buttons,they made a scroll to particular id of the same page..